# How does a UIStoryBoard change on iphone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard

I have an already shipped app on App Store that made use of Storyboard.

I see from the keynote, comparing to previous model that iPhone 5 has a taller screen.

I wonder how this will impact on my esisting storyboard, because from my 'app point of view' there's only one difference which is the background.png. All the rest is just plain UITableView that can just fit more rows.

I cannot find any document for this on Apple site (I have always been so noob in finding things on Apple developer site).
Has anyone made adjustment to his already developed and published app to match with new layout ?
If yes, do I have to develop a brand new storyboard, or is there an adjustment to be done with code ?

[UPDATE]

I am reporting my experience, now that Xcode 4.5 is long shipped for development.
Xcode itself, as some suggested, asked me if I would like to enable tallest screen support by creating a default png. After saying yes, I had to enter each segue in storyboard for some adjustment, change png background (which was unstrechable by design) with a tallest one, change stretching settings and redeploy.

It has been an annoying work because I have quite some segues, and Xcode doesn't allow to reuse templates within Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old apps without 1136x640 resolution support will run letterboxed, with black areas on top and bottom.

You can enable new layout support for existing project simply by supplying new `Default-568h@2x.png` loading screen. Take heed though, you'll have to test your old interface on both old and new resolution (via iOS Simulator) to make sure everything looks good and works as designed.

Comment: Having application letterboxed is something I would like to avoid. What would happen with Storyboard after supplying new default png ?

Comment: Well, main view for each view controller should stretch properly, if you didn't change their default autoresizing mask. As for any other subviews - you should check manually. If you use only standard view controllers without heavy modifications to their behaviour, you should be ok.

Comment: I started a new project in xCode5 and had the same issue. I had to repeat the process of adding the launcher image with the size 1136x640 till it worked also on iPhone 5 devices. I didn't change anything inside the settings and don't choose the storyboard programmatically. Looks to me like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Its been said when iphone 5 is launched that your app view will be filled with black color on top and bottom if it is not taking account for the increase size ( not designed for iphone5 screen) 
so your app will just work fine but will have black border on both and top to filled the extra space..

Comment: Yes, but how can you 'take account for the increase size' with Storyboard ? Develop another storyboard specific for iPhone 5 or by managing this by code ?